# Hay manera de prevenir que las POST Request de Swagger generen entradas en la dB?

Tags: laravel, swagger, swagger-ui

Ya realicé toda la documentación de mi backend utilizando Swagger, hay manera de prevenir que las POST Request de Swagger generen entradas en la dB o enviar un parametro oculto para el usuario que me sirva para manejar desde el lado del BE la consulta y evitar que se generen registros en la DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puntualmente para este caso lo que hice fue capturar la url de origen desde la cual se le esta pegando al endpoint y de esa manera lo manejo desde el lado del back.

Comment: o sea.. estas usando la base de produccion para test??? porque es basicamente lo que estas diciendo aca

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga Lamentablemente para alguno de nuestros clientes no existen instancias QA, por lo tanto teniamos que desarrollar algun tipo de work-arround con respecto a este problema. Otra opcion que se barajó fue crear una DB test para todos los clientes sin QA y con la ayuda de un cron vaciarla diariamente.

Answer (score 2):

Hola te diría que no se puede. Swagger está hecho para ser "fiel" a tu back por lo que los parámetros son los mismos. Y con ello todas las llamadas.

Piensa que swagger se creó para que los desarrolladores tuviésemos una forma fácil y rápida de ver como funcionan las APIS a las que vamos a conectarnos de ahí que sean 1:1, es como hacer las llamadas desde postman.

Lo normal es que no se inserten datos basura desde swagger a no ser que sea que apunte a una base de datos de test (que suelen eliminarse cada X tiempo)